# php regular expression convert to python code

Tags: php, python, regex

i have this code written in php, and i want to convert it into python code

```
$title_regex = "/<title>(.+)<\/title>/i";
preg_match_all($title_regex, $string, $title, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$url_title = $title[1];

/// fecth decription
$tags = get_meta_tags($url);

// fetch images
$image_regex = '/<img[^>]*'.'src=[\"|\'](.*)[\"|\']/Ui';
preg_match_all($image_regex, $string, $img, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$images_array = $img[1];
```

i have tried this .. but it give me errors in pics part

```
import re
out=Data #web site html page ..
title_regex = "/<title>(.+)<\/title>/i" #no need for this .. un used 
m = re.search("<title>(.+)<\/title>", out)
print "title",m.group(1)
#for pics i have tried this but it give me error ..
pics = re.match(r"/<img[^>]*'.'src=[\"|\'](.*)[\"|\']/Ui", out)#the conversion is not correct  
print "grop",pics.group(1)
```

my full code

```
import re
import urllib
print "Start"
url="http://www.deviantart.com"
data=urllib.urlopen(url)
out=data.read()
print 
title_regex = "/<title>(.+)<\/title>/i"
m = re.search("<title>(.+)<\/title>", out)
print "first",m
print "title=",m.group(1)

title_regex = "/<title>(.+)<\/title>/i"

pics = re.match(r"/<img[^>]*src=[\"|\'](.*)[\"|\']/Ui", out)

print "pics>>",pics.group(1)
```

how i can convert a php re>>"/]*'.'src=\"|\'[\"|\']/Ui"  to a python re ?

Comment: for title it works .. for pics it give me error .. no fully work

Comment: Um yeah, **what** error?

Comment: the error you get is this ? AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: look at my code , i think it works now

Comment: aaarrgh, regular expressions for tag matching! Use a proper parser like BeautifulSoup instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the regular expression probably did not find anything.

try this :
also remove the /Ui at the end

```
import re
out=Data #web site html page ..
title_regex = "/<title>(.+)<\/title>/i" #no need for this .. un used 
if m is not None:  #  NEW  <----------------
   m = re.search("<title>(.+)<\/title>", out)
print "title",m.group(1)
#for pics i have tried this but it give me error ..
pics = re.match(r"<img[^>]*src=[\"|\'](.*)[\"|\']", out)
if pics is not None: # NEW <----------------
   print "grop",pics.group(1)
```

for you 2nd question try this

```
for filename in pics.groups():
    print filename
```

Comment: print "grop",m.group(1)
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: put before that one another if - if m is not None:

Comment: if my answer helped you solve your problem mark it as the correct one :)

Comment: the python conversion of pics is not right .. the page contain pics

Comment: change the . to + (string concatenation)

Comment: ok remove the /Ui at the end, i have changed my code and also remove the / before the <img

Comment: a little question .. how i can retrive all images .. what i suppose to do ?

Comment: do this:  for match in pics.groups():

Comment: it give me only the first pics >> http://st.deviantart.net/minish/main/logo.png" width="125" height="42

Answer (score 0):

Working version .. display all images from a given web site using tag IMG src >
code:

```
  import re
  import urllib
  print "Start"
  url="http://www.deviantart.com"
  data=urllib.urlopen(url)
  out=data.read()
  print 
  title_regex = "/<title>(.+)<\/title>/i"
  m = re.search("<title>(.+)<\/title>", out)
  print "first",m
  print "grop",m.group(1)

  title_regex = "/<title>(.+)<\/title>/i"

  pics = re.compile(r"<IMG[^>]*src=([^>]*[^/])")#Change IMG tag 
  allpics=pics.findall(out)
  print "found",pics
  for mypic in allpics:
     print "< IMG src=",mypic
```

thanks all